# How to suppress qt.pointer.dispatch warning

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

Since upgrading from PyQt5 to PyQt6, I have been getting the following warning whenever my mouse enters or leaves a pyqtgraph `GraphicsView` widget:

```
qt.pointer.dispatch: skipping QEventPoint(id=0 ts=0 [...]) : no target window
```

This seems to come directly from Qt and not PyQt, but it doesn't have any consequences on the running code (i.e. everything seems to be running fine).

Is there any way to silence it?

Comment: Probably related to [QTBUG-103935](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-103935). Are you on macOS and are you using the touchpad?

Answer (score 1):

Following [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)'s comment, I found out this is related to touch events from the track pad on macOS with QGraphicsView.

The fix seems to be to set `WA_AcceptTouchEvents` to `False` e.g.:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
win.viewport().setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_AcceptTouchEvents, False)
```

Note that this may have some consequences if the application is designed to accept touch events (such as on mobile devices).